# Create Related Data using Nested attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

api. Now need to insert a record which has associated records. I read nested attributes but didn't get any idea. I can't understand well.

I tried with one example in rails mvc project but even i can't create associated record in one-one mapping itself. Please guid me what the steps to do this or any good articles with sample?

Anyway the following is my workings

My model is

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office_assignment
  has_many :departments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :office_assignment
end

class OfficeAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```

My controller methods for create

```
def new
    @instructor = Instructor.new
  end

  def create
    @instructor = Instructor.new(instructor_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @instructor.save

        format.html { redirect_to @instructor, notice: 'Instructor was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @instructor }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @instructor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_instructor
      @instructor = Instructor.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def instructor_params
      params.require(:instructor).permit(:LastName, :FirstMidName, :HireDate, office_assignment_attributes: [:Location])
    end
```

My create form

```
<%= form_for @instructor, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal instructor" } do |f| %>

    <% if @instructor.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@instructor.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this instructor from being saved:</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
        <% @instructor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :LastName, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :LastName, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@instructor[:LastName]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :FirstMidName, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :FirstMidName, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@instructor[:FirstMidName]) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :HireDate, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :HireDate, :class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= error_span(@instructor[:HireDate]) %>
  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Location, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="office_assignment_Location" class ="form-control">
      </div>
      <%= error_span(@instructor[:HireDate]) %>
    </div>


  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            instructors_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

Please guide me..

**Edit:**

Changes in html file

```
<%= f.fields_for :office_assignment_Location do |loc| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= loc.label :Location, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= loc.text_field :Location %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= loc.link_to_add "Add Location", :office_assignment_Location , :class=>'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

My param in controller

```
def instructor_params
  params.require(:instructor).permit(:LastName, :FirstMidName, :HireDate, office_assignment_attributes: [:id, :Location ,:_destroy])
end
```

My schema

```
create_table "instructors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "LastName",     limit: 255
    t.string   "FirstMidName", limit: 255
    t.date     "HireDate"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
  end

  create_table "office_assignments", primary_key: "Instructor_Id", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "Location",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "office_assignments", "instructors", column: "Instructor_Id"
```

Comment: Could you please show the schema to get more idea about it.

Comment: You need to type the nested format inside the form, so please share the schema.

Comment: @Akhil : I have post the answer please let me know it works or not?

Comment: hi friends thanks i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

FYI: attribute's name should start with small letter not capital.

Here are some changes:

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office_assignment , :dependent => :destroy # add dependent destroy
  has_many :departments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :office_assignment,  :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true # add allow destroy
end
```

Some change in strong Parameters:

```
 def instructor_params
      params.require(:instructor).permit(:LastName, :FirstMidName, :HireDate, office_assignment_attributes: [:id, :Lesson ,:_destroy])
    end
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add `:id` and `:_destroy` in `office_assignment_attributes`

Now in View(form_template):

Instead of this:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :Location, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="office_assignment_Location" class ="form-control">
      </div>
      <%= error_span(@instructor[:HireDate]) %>
    </div>
```

It should be:

```
<%= nested_form_for @instructor, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal instructor" } do |f| %>

......
.....

<%= f.fields_for :office_assignment do |loc| %>
      <div class="form-group">
       <%= loc.label :Location, :class => 'control-label' %>
        <div class="controls"> 
          <%= loc.text_field :Location %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
     <%= f.link_to_add "Add Location", :office_assignment , :class=>'btn btn-primary'%>
```

You have to create nested form like this. I hope this helps you.

**Note:** Use `nested_form_for` instead of `form_for` in your form:
For your reference:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: Hi,  I think i need to research more. I changed as per your suggestion but now create page is error with **'ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `link_to_add' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f7d3c00b4a8>):'** . But i added helper in application helper

Comment: @Akhil : no need to add any helper method in application helper file.  install `gem "nested_form"` and in application.js file add `//= require jquery_nested_form`

Comment: @Akhil : I have updated the answer for model with `:reject_if => :all_blank` and restart the server then try

Comment: I updated and same error raising. I don't any other mistake so i updated my changes in my question. Yes i updated :reject_if also

Comment: @Akhil : I have updated my Answer. I found that you had use `form_for` which was giving you error. Use 'nested_form_for` Check my updated answer and keep that `<%= f.link_to_add "Add Location", :office_assignment_Location , :class=>'btn btn-primary'%>` out of loop only

Comment: Thanks now it shows error as **Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :office_assignment_Location association** so something related to attribute

Comment: replace `:office_assignment_Location` with `:office_assignment`

Comment: thanks @Gagan Gami . Now create page shown with one Add Location button. But i am not clear that how i add location along with instructor. Nothing happened when i clicked Add Location button. please explain

Comment: So you mean that data are not stored in db? Or Data which you entered are not seen(location). Check that data are entered in db?

Comment: Yes not saved. Also i don't get any text box to add location. I got Add Location button just before save button. When i save instructor is inserted but nothing happened in location. If you are ok please help in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75932/discussion-between-akhil-and-gagan-gami).